# Ad Hoc .ipa install doesn't save device token to Parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform, ipa

Thanks to the comprehensive knowledge available in this web community I managed to complete my first iPhone app, almost i.e.
Everything works fine if app is directly installed with Xcode, but when I create and install an Archive file for Ad Hoc distribution it doesn't save the device token to Parse. Provisioning Profile for Ad Hoc distribution is valid and PNs are enabled. Thanks in advance for any hints.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    [currentInstallation setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:@"owner"];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}
```

@owner is also not being created.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone made the same mistake: I forgot to upload my new p12 certificate file to Parse push settings.